# Python Django: Get what input field the cursor is in?

Tags: python, html, django

I am relatively new to Django and don’t have a lot of experience with python.
So far I display some input fields this way, where I'm looping through a range and then making the equivalent amount of fields. **But is there some way to know which field is active, like what field is the cursor in?**

The reason for why I want to know what field is active is because I have created a list with a bunch of special symbols, like math symbols and Greek letters, which the user can click, I then want the active field to display the clicked symbol. hope it makes sense

I was made aware of something called `focus` but I don’t think I understand how to use it. If someone could explain it would be great

This is the "important" part of my `.html` file

```
{% with ''|center:number_of_variables as range %}
        {% for i in range %}

            <input type="text"  name="know_variable_description{{ forloop.counter0}}" placeholder="Symbol" >
            <input type="text"  name="know_variable_symbol{{ forloop.counter0}}" placeholder="Name" >

            {{ forloop.counter0}}
            
        {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the input field, you can use the `onfocus` event

```
<input type="text" onfocus="myFunction()" name="know_variable_description{{ forloop.counter0}}" placeholder="Symbol" >
```

The `onfocus` event will call the function `myFunction` whenever the input is focused(active), and you can put your other logic in the function `myFunction` in javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try it out, and get back to you

Comment: Is it possible to pass something to that function? In my case i want to pass `forloop.counter0`